# return nested array solidity

Tags: arrays, nested, return, solidity

Is it possible to return an array in solidity?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Test {
    constructor() {}
    function multiArray() external pure returns (uint256[2][] memory doubleArray) {
        doubleArray[0] = [uint(12345678),uint(1234567)];
      return doubleArray;
    }
}
```

this does not work, but I thought with solidity > 0.8.0 it should be possible, also with "ABIEncoderV2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested arrays are still incomplete but they work at a certain level.
Currently, **nested arrays can only be used within an internal call** to functions that are either private or internal. They should also be stored in storage or memory.
The biggest issue is using them in the calldata as a parameter or return statement which is not yet supported.
I'll recommend trying to find another way to return the nested array information like a mapping, struct, or even returning multiple lists and then working with them inside the function.
Another alternative is to **pass the data as bytes and extract the array data or vice-versa**. However, this can have a high gas cost on large arrays and some other problems. To use this method you can take advantage of the new ABI encoder.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity support 1D array only. Multidimensional arrays are yet to come.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0;
pragma  solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract Test{
    string[] A=["A","B"];
    function fun() public view  returns(string[] memory){
        return A;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the array first and then return values by index. You can also use a mapping, but keep in mind you can't easily iterate over it.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract NestedArrays{
    
    mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) mappingArray;
    uint256[2][] multiArray;

    constructor(){
        multiArray.push([1,2]);
        multiArray.push([3,4]);

        mappingArray[0] = [10,20];
        mappingArray[1] = [30,40];
    }

    function getMultiArray() public view returns(uint256[2][] memory){
        return multiArray;
    }

    function getMultiArrayMember(uint256 index) public view returns(uint256[2] memory){
        require(multiArray.length > index, "wrong index");
        return multiArray[index];
    }

    function getMappingArrayMember(uint256 index) public view returns(uint256[] memory){
        return mappingArray[index];
    }
}
```